# select max value of a row from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Please i am trying to query data with a maximum value from two tables,

```
table1
|user_id | name |
| 001    | Paul |
| 002    | Sean |


table2
|id  | class | Year | user_id |
|201 |  1A   | 2010 |  001    |
|202 |  2A   | 2011 |  001    |
|203 |  1B   | 2010 |  002    |
```

The `user_id` in `table2` references the `user_id` from `table1`

This is how i want my output to be

```
OUTPUT
 | user_id | name | class| year |
 | 001     | Paul | 2A   | 2011 |
 | 002     | Sean | 1B   | 2010 |
```

**TRIED SO FAR**

```
SELECT 
       a.user_id,
       a.name,
       b.class,
       max(Year) as year
FROM
       table1 a
INNER JOIN
           table2 b
    ON
           a.user_id=b.user_id

GROUP BY user_id
```

This query above gives me a maximum year with a different class value in a row, thus the previous class value. This is how it looks like

```
 | user_id | name | class| year |
 | 001     | Paul | 1A   | 2011 |
 | 002     | Sean | 1B   | 2010 |
```

Please where am i going wrong in my query? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could order the full result set first by year, and then group by user id:

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT 
       a.user_id,
       a.name,
       b.class,
       year
FROM
       table1 a
INNER JOIN
           table2 b
    ON
           a.user_id=b.user_id
ORDER BY year desc

) h
GROUP BY user_id
```

[SqlFiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29485e/4)

Comment: Hello, @lpg, i have made a follow up question on this answer. Can you please help..http://stackoverflow.com/q/24737959/2595059 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `group by` already, you can use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` hack:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.name,
       substring_index(group_concat(b.class order by year desc), ',', 1) as maxclass
       max(Year) as year
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.user_id=b.user_id
GROUP BY a.user_id, a.name;
```

You can also do this without a `group by`, using `not exists`:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.name, b.class, b.year
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.user_id=b.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from table2 b2 where b2.user_id = b.user_id and b2.year > b.year)
```

The `where` clause rephrases the query.  It says:  "Get me all rows from `table2` where the same user does not have a bigger `year`."  This is equivalent to getting the row with the maximum year.  And, this is standard SQL, which often works quite well in any database.

Comment: Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery

```
SELECT 
       a.user_id,
       a.name,
       (Select class  FROM table2 where year = max(b.year)) as class,
       max(b.Year) as year
FROM
       table1 a,table2 b
WHERE
      a.user_id=b.user_id
```