# Count unread messages from a sender

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a messaging system using mysql and php. I have gotten to a point where I want to select messages received by a user and also count the unread messages received from different users to the same user. I have illustrated it below

```
table----users
perID | name |
 001  | mum  |
 002  | tok  |
 003  | sat  |

table----messages
msgID |senderID | msgBody |      msgTime       | deleted_by_sender |
 200  | 002     | Hello   | 2014-07-13 19:14:22|  no               |
 201  | 002     | Mate    | 2014-07-13 19:14:29|  no               |
 202  | 003     | hi mum  | 2014-07-13 19:19:12|  no               |
 203  | 003     | How     | 2014-07-13 19:19:52|  no               |
```

the `senderID` references from the parent table `users`

```
   table----recipients
 recID |msgID |recipientID | msgStatus| deleted_by_recipient|       
 310   | 200  |    001     |  unread  |        no           |
 311   | 201  |    001     |  unread  |        no           |
 312   | 202  |    001     |  read    |        no           |
 313   | 203  |    001     |  read    |        no           |
```

the `recipientID` references the parent table `users`

I want to

```
1. Get only the current message received by the recipient with recipientID=001
    if it is not deleted by the recipient.

2. count the number of unread messages received from the individual users.
```

something like below

```
senderID | msgID | unread |
   002   |  201  |  2     |
   003   |  203  |  0     |
```

My query below works as expected but, it hides the last row because it has no unread value in the `msgStatus` column,
but i wish that all rows would be returned even if the `msgStatus` has no value. It should also be in one optimized query.

```
SELECT *,count(msgStatus) As unread  
FROM (
        SELECT
                m.senderID,
                m.msgTime,
                u.perID,
                r.recipientID,
                r.msgID,
                r.msgStatus,
                r.deleted_by_recipient
        FROM 
                messages m
        INNER JOIN 
                users u
            ON 
                m.senderID=u.perID
        INNER JOIN
                recipients r
            ON
                r.msgID=m.msgID

        ORDER BY msgTime DESC
    )h 
WHERE 
    recipientID=12 and 
    deleted_by_recipient ='no' and 
    msgStatus='unread'
GROUP BY perID
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want with conditional aggregation.  The idea is to move the conditions from the `where` clause to the `select` clause:

```
select senderid,
       max(case when r.deleted_by_recipient = 'no' and r.recipientID = '001' then m.msgID end
          ) as CurrentMsg,
       sum(r.msgStatus = 'unread') as unread
from messages m left outer join
     recipients r
     on  m.msgID = r.msgID
group by senderid;
```

I'm not 100% sure that this implements your logic:

1. This assumes that the most recent message is the one with the largest `MsgID`.  Basing it on another field is possible, most easily done with a `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick.
2. This is counting all unread messages regardless of the recipient.  Once again, this is easily fixed by changing the logic inside the `sum()`.
3. Your sample data doesn't have duplicates (the same `MsgId` with multiple recipients).  If this is possible, you may need to change the logic for the counting.  Once again, this is not difficult, it is just unclear whether the additional work is necessary.

Comment: @George here is a SQL FIDDLE with the answer showing it works.. it needed a simple edit but works like a charm :) ------ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6529d/1

Comment: This still counts all unread messages in the msgStatus regardless of the recipient.Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please can't my query above be modified to suit my case?

Comment: @George . . . That is point number (2).  You can fix this by adding a `where` clause limiting all the results to one recipient.